# running python code depending on mqtt response

Tags: python, mqtt

I have a python code which can set the power of a bike using ANT+ protocol. I have connected this python code to `mqtt` server, using `mqtt` I would like to send the power of the bike (an int), if the power receive from `mqtt server` is different from the previous power I would like to set the new power (from the python code).

Here is my code. I am not sure if I use the on_message function correctly. Actually, inside the code I should give parameters but I don't know which one to give...

The `if` is inside the `process` function, it's inside the `process` function that I set the power of the bike. So I'd like to run the `process` function if the message receive from MQTT is different from the previous (power, so the previous message). So whenever I change the power inside the `MQTT server`, the python code send a message to the bike to set the power...

```
import sys
import time
from ant.core import driver, node, event, message, log
from ant.core.constants import CHANNEL_TYPE_TWOWAY_TRANSMIT, TIMEOUT_NEVER
from ant.core.constants import CHANNEL_TYPE_TWOWAY_RECEIVE, TIMEOUT_NEVER

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt #import the client1
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe

broker_address="127.0.0.1"
topic = 'NameMeasurement'
client = mqtt.Client("P1") #create new instance
client.connect(broker_address) #connect to broker

power = 0x01

def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
    #print("message received " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    return int(str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))


class MONARK(event.EventCallback):

    def __init__(self, serial, netkey):
        print('init')
        self.serial = serial
        self.netkey = netkey
        self.eventCount = 0
        self.eventTime = 0
        self.cumulativePower = 0
        self.instantaneousPower = 0
        self.antnode = None
        self.channel = None

    def start(self):
        print('start')
        #print("starting node")
        self._start_antnode()
        self._setup_channel()
        self.channel.registerCallback(self)
        #print("start listening for hr events")

    def stop(self):
        if self.channel:
            self.channel.close()
            self.channel.unassign()
        if self.antnode:
            self.antnode.stop()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
        self.stop()

    def _start_antnode(self):
        print('start antnode')
        stick = driver.USB2Driver(self.serial)
        self.antnode = node.Node(stick)
        self.antnode.start()

    def _setup_channel(self):
        print('setup channel')
        key = node.NetworkKey('N:ANT+', self.netkey)
        self.antnode.setNetworkKey(0, key)
        self.channel = self.antnode.getFreeChannel()
        self.channel.name = 'C:HRM'
        
        self.channel.assign('N:ANT+', CHANNEL_TYPE_TWOWAY_RECEIVE)
            
        self.channel.setID(17, 0, 0)
        self.channel.setSearchTimeout(TIMEOUT_NEVER)
        self.channel.setPeriod(8182)
        self.channel.setFrequency(57)
        self.channel.open()
        self.process()
        print('open')

    def process(self):

        #if isinstance(msg, message.ChannelBroadcastDataMessage):
        #print('test')

        client.on_message=on_message #attach function to callback
        client.loop_start() #start the loop
        print("Subscribing to topic")
        client.subscribe(topic)
        if (on_message() != power):
            power = on_message()

        time.sleep(4) # wait
        client.loop_stop() #stop the loop

        self.eventCount = self.eventCount + 1
        print(self.eventCount)

        payload = chr(0x31)  # standard power-only message
        payload += chr(0xFF)
        payload += chr(0xFF)  # Pedal power not used
        payload += chr(0xFF)  # Cadence not used
        payload += chr(0xFF)
        payload += chr(0xFF)
        payload += chr(0xFF)
        payload += chr(power)
    
        ant_msg = message.ChannelBroadcastDataMessage(self.channel.number, data=payload)
        sys.stdout.write('+')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print 'Write message to ANT stick on channel ' + repr(self.channel.number)
        self.antnode.driver.write(ant_msg.encode())
        self.process()

        msg = subscribe.simple("bike", hostname=broker_address)
        print("%s %s" % (msg.topic, msg.payload))

            
SERIAL = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
NETKEY = 'B9A521FBBD72C345'.decode('hex')


with MONARK(serial=SERIAL, netkey=NETKEY) as monark:
    monark.start()
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
            input("Press enter to Stop\n")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your model is wrong here.

Firstly, the `on_message()` function doesn't return anything. The return statement will not do what you are expecting here.

Secondly, you can not call the `on_message()` function from your own code, it is called by the MQTT client on the client's network thread when a message is delivered.

You have a couple of options for how to make this work.

1. Connect to the broker, start the network loop and subscribe to the topic in the `__init__()` function. Then have the `on_message()` callback set a variable on the `MONARK` class. You can then access this variable every time you call `process()`.
2. Set up the MQTT client the same as in the last option, but instead of setting a variable on the class the `on_message()` function can call `process()` every time a new message arrives and pass the new value as an argument to `process()`.

Comment: ok thank you for helping me! Why my `on_message()` function does not return anything. I am trying your first option. So instead of managing the subscibe in the process() function, I do all this stuff in my __init__() function ? Where do I put my variable inside the MONARK class ? Sorry for stupid question, trying to understand how those python code works... thanks

Comment: `on_message` is never meant to be called by your code, it is called by the MQTT Client and it doesn't expect the method to return anything. I suggest you look up Python class member variables.